# Stanford Core NLP ner 4.0.0 Error: Could not find or load main class stanford-ner.jar;lib.*

Tags: java, error-handling, stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a NER model with Stanford CoreNLP however it cannot find the main class. I have included the paths to the jar files in my CLASSPATH yet it still cannot locate them. Any way to fix this please?

C:\Users\apaul\Desktop\CoreNLP\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0\stanford-ner-4.0.0>java -cp "C:\Users\apaul\Desktop\CoreNLP\stanford-ner-4.0.0*" -mx3g stanford-ner.jar;lib/* edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier classifiers\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -textFile file
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:  -Xmx256M
Error: Could not find or load main class stanford-ner.jar;lib.*

Answer (score 0):

1.) cd into `C:\Users\apaul\Desktop\CoreNLP\stanford-corenlp-4.0.0\stanford-ner-4.0.0`

2.) Create a training props file and put it in that directory. For this example call it my-model.props.

```
# location of training data
trainFileList = /path/to/conll.3class.train
# location of test data
testFile = /path/to/all.3class.test
# where to store the saved model
serializeTo = ner.model.ser.gz

type = crf

wordFunction = edu.stanford.nlp.process.AmericanizeFunction

useDistSim = false

# establish the data file format
map = word=0,answer=1

saveFeatureIndexToDisk = true

useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useLongSequences=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
maxLeft=1
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
useOccurrencePatterns=true
useLastRealWord=true
useNextRealWord=true
normalize=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useDisjunctive=true
disjunctionWidth=5

readerAndWriter=edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ColumnDocumentReaderAndWriter

useObservedSequencesOnly=true

useQN = true
QNsize = 25

# makes it go faster
featureDiffThresh=0.05
```

3.) run `java -cp "*" -Xmx3g edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop my-model.props` in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you so much! the only problem im facing now is this error: Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: argsToProperties could not read properties file: my-model.props

Comment: What directory did you put my-model.props in vs. what directory are you running the command?